# Tiny node js video convert server, best way to manage the threads

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am developing a small server to convert videos for the web, I started with a TCP server (maybe it is not the best solution, but it is not the part of my problem right now) to which I send the path of videos to convert and then Add to a queue in a database system, in this case mysql, but I'm thinking of migrating to MongoDB when it works

```
var net = require('net'),
    Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
    async = require('async'),
    JsonSocket = require('json-socket'),
    ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
var sequelize = new Sequelize(configDB.url);

var Videos    = sequelize.import('app/models/video');
Videos.sync();

var port = 9838;

var server = net.createServer();
server.listen(port);
server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket = new JsonSocket(socket);
    socket.on('message', function(video) {
        console.log(video.video);
        db_data = {
            'name': video.video,
            'converted': false,
            'progress': 0,
            'status': 'Q',
        }
        Videos.create(db_data).then(function () {
            socket.sendMessage('New Video Added');
        }).catch(function () {
            console.log('Error adding Video');
            socket.sendMessage('Error adding video')
        });
    });
});
```

Once I have a list of videos on the database the process begin with this code:

```
// Function to update the video status on the database
var databaseUpdate = function(status, callback) {
    name = status.name;
    delete status["name"];
    Videos.update(status, {
        where: {
            name: name
        }
    }).then(function (video) {
        if (typeof callback === 'function' && callback) callback();
    });
}

//convert the video:
// If the video status are:
//   - 'Q' for in queue
//   - 'R' for running conversion
//   - 'C' for complete
//   - 'E' for error on the conversion proccess
function ffmpegConvert(video, output, callback)
{
    var filename = video.split('/').reverse()[0].split('.')[0],
        output = output  + filename + '.mp4';  

    ffmpeg(video)
        .videoCodec('libx264')
        .audioCodec('libmp3lame')
        .on('error', function(err) {
            db_data = {
                'name': video,
                'status': 'E',   //<- set status if error ocurre
            }
            databaseUpdate(db_data)
            console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
        })
        .on('end', function(stdout, stderr) {
            db_data = {
                'name': video,
                'converted': true,       //<- set status complete conversion
                'status': 'C',           //<- set status complete conversion
            }
            databaseUpdate(db_data, function(){convertVideos(1)}) // <- put a next video in the queue to convert
        })
        .on('progress', function(progress) {
            db_data = {
                'name': video,
                'status': 'R',                //<- set status ass running conversion
                'progress': progress.percent, //<- set the video processes %
            }
            databaseUpdate(db_data)
        })
        .save(output);
}

// get videos not converted `converted: false` and with
// queque status `status: 'Q'` from the database 
// the send to the ffmpegConvert function in a num of async task
var convertVideos = function(num){
    Videos.findAll(
        {
            where: {
                converted: false,
                status: 'Q'
            }, 
            limit : num, 
            order: '"createdAt" DESC'
        }
    ).then(function (videos) {
        if (videos && videos.length){
            async.each(videos,
                function(item){
                    ffmpegConvert(item.name, output_folder )
                },
            function(err){
            });
        }
    });
}


// Start vidieo conversion with threads number equal to number of cpu    
threads  = require('os').cpus().length,
convertVideos(threads);
```

So at this point All works great, and all the videos on the queue are converted, but my questions are:

**1 - How to put new videos to convert if they are added to the database after the first run on the server?**

I can't put it to run the `socket.on('message', function(video) {}` because if I send a new video when the queue is not completed this going to start a new separated thread. I also think that I have to find a way to monitor the **async** task to see how many task are running before send new one

**2 - How to manage uncompleted videos if server goes down?**

If I turn off the server for some reason, the status of the current video in the database stay in 'R' so the query to add it to the conversion prosses didn not see it, and left it corrupted.